# Storybook error: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I am having this issue where in my storybook test one of my component's import is not getting properly imported. It works fine when I run my app just not when I run storybook. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have tried several things like changing the const to a function, export default and non-defaults separately etc.

The error occurs at this line:

```
errorMessage={t('intake.health_profile_card_error')}
```

The function I am trying to use
[image]

And here's my storybook test
[image]

And my component[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtPIT.png)

[image]
[image]

Comment: At which line this error appears?

Comment: at errorMessage={t('intake.health_profile_card_error')}

Comment: Please paste code and not images.